# Hot to cut out text in string that varies?

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I was just curious if there was a way to delete text from a string or only capture specific text when the string varies in info.

Exmaples of the strings I'm working:

```
3/5/2019 12:38 PM
10/30/2019 6:32 AM
9/12/2019 9:53 AM
```

I want to be able to extract the date and hour of the day separately and append them to a list. However obviously those vary and even the index of the hour can change as the day, month or hour can become > 10 which can push it back up to three spaces.

Comment: `re.compile(r"[\s\/:]").split(s)` should return the numbers and `PM` in a list.

Comment: How much do the strings vary? Can you give an example of a few different types of strings you're looking at?

There are a variety of regular-expression-style approaches you could take to get the information you're looking for

Comment: @TaylorNelms 3/5/2019 12:38 PM      10/15/2018 6:38 AM       7/11/2019 10:32 AM   I'm not worried about the hour of day however cause it only goes from 6AM to 4PM so there wont be any overlap in the AM or PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

s = "3/5/2019 12:38 PM"
result = re.compile(r"[\s\/:]").split(s)
```

`result`:

```
['3', '5', '2019', '12', '38', 'PM']
```

This should solve your problem assuming the delimiter when the string come in are the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)
something likes this:

```
import re
m = re.match("(\d+/\d+/\d+) (\d+:\d+) (\wM)", "3/5/2019 12:38 PM")
print(m.groups())
```

this will print a tuple with the first item being the date and second item being the time and the third item being the PM or AM: `('3/5/2019', '12:38', 'PM')` which you can easily parse yourself

**Edit**

you can also use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime) module to parse the date string:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("3/5/2019 12:38 PM","%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p")
print(dt.date(), dt.hour)
```

which will give you a datetime object which you can get all the information from